# Spring StoredProcedure Object Return List of Object

Tags: mysql, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I using mysql stored procedure which uses to retrieve list of object. Is this possible ?

I'm following this [article](http://www.luv2code.com/2011/11/10/calling-stored-procedures-with-spring-jdbc-templates/)

Question:

1. How to retrieve the list of object like in select statement using result set ?
2. How to map the result set to list of object ?

   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `generateLCRReport`(IN `countryCodeParam` INT, OUT `countryCode` INT, OUT `dialCode` INT, OUT `custPrefix` VARCHAR(50), OUT `vendorPrefix` VARCHAR(50), OUT `custPrice` FLOAT, OUT `vendorCost` FLOAT, OUT `profit` FLOAT)
       LANGUAGE SQL
       DETERMINISTIC
       READS SQL DATA
       SQL SECURITY DEFINER
       COMMENT 'generateLCRReport'
   BEGIN
   select c.country_code as countryCode, c.dial_code as dialCode,
   c.customer_prefix as custPrefix, c.vendor_prefix as vendorPrefix,
   max(cust_rate.rate) as custPrice, min(ven_rate.rate) as vendorCost,
   round(max(cust_rate.rate) - min(ven_rate.rate), 3) as profit
   from cdr c

   inner join
   (select a.id, r.rate, re.country_code, re.dial_code, ap.prefix from rate r
   inner join region re on r.region_id = re.id
   inner join account_prefix ap on r.account_prefix_id = ap.id
   inner join account a on a.id = ap.account_id
   where ap.prefix_type = 0
   ) as cust_rate

   on c.country_code = cust_rate.country_code
   and c.dial_code = cust_rate.dial_code
   and c.customer_prefix = cust_rate.prefix
   and c.customer_id = cust_rate.id

   inner join
   (select a.id, r.rate, re.country_code, re.dial_code, ap.prefix from rate r
   inner join region re on r.region_id = re.id
   inner join account_prefix ap on r.account_prefix_id = ap.id
   inner join account a on a.id = ap.account_id
   where ap.prefix_type = 1
   ) as ven_rate

   on c.country_code = ven_rate.country_code
   and c.dial_code = ven_rate.dial_code
   and c.vendor_prefix = ven_rate.prefix
   and c.vendor_id = ven_rate.id
   where c.country_code = countryCodeParam
   group by c.country_code and c.dial_code
   order by c.country_code asc
   limit 5000;

   END

   public class LCRReportSP extends StoredProcedure {

   ```
   /**
    * 
    */
   @Autowired
   public LCRReportSP(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String storedProcName, RowMapper<CostReport> mapper) {
       super(jdbcTemplate, storedProcName);

       SqlReturnResultSet rs = new SqlReturnResultSet("", mapper);
       SqlOutParameter outParam = new SqlOutParameter("countryCode", Types.INTEGER);
       SqlOutParameter outParam1 = new SqlOutParameter("dialCode", Types.INTEGER);
       SqlOutParameter outParam2 = new SqlOutParameter("custPrefix", Types.VARCHAR);
       SqlOutParameter outParam3 = new SqlOutParameter("vendorPrefix", Types.VARCHAR);
       SqlOutParameter outParam4 = new SqlOutParameter("custPrice", Types.FLOAT);
       SqlOutParameter outParam5 = new SqlOutParameter("vendorCost", Types.FLOAT);
       SqlOutParameter outParam6 = new SqlOutParameter("profit", Types.FLOAT);

       this.declareParameter(rs);
       this.declareParameter(outParam);
       this.declareParameter(outParam1);
       this.declareParameter(outParam2);
       this.declareParameter(outParam3);
       this.declareParameter(outParam4);
       this.declareParameter(outParam5);
       this.declareParameter(outParam6);

       this.setFunction(false);
       this.compile();
   }

   /**
    * @param countryCode
    * @return
    */
   public Map<String, ?> generateLCRReport(int countryCode) {

       Map<String, Object> inParam = new HashMap<String, Object>();

       inParam.put("countryCodeParam", new Integer(countryCode));

       return this.execute(inParam);
   }
   ```

   }

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try `resultSetExtractor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using RowMapper and declared parameter SqlReturnResultSet.